# Calling a class function with pointers issue

Tags: c++, pointers, syntax

I am getting this error with my code.

error C2228: left of '.showHand' must have class/struct/union
1>type is 'PokerHand *' did you intend to use '->' instead?

This is the part of my main function that is getting the error. The error thing is the one where I call showHand()

```
PokerHand* Dog = Wood.dealN(5);
Dog.showHand();
```

I'm guessing I'm doing something incorrectly with pointers which is why the error is telling me to use `->`, however I'm not sure where I would even put this in my code. I just need to be able to call the `showHand()` function in my main file, as far as I know every other part of the code is working.

Comment: Dog is a pointer so you need to use -> ... usually if the intelesens doesnt go on your using the wrong accesser.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line:

```
Dog.showHand();
```

Should be:

```
Dog->showHand();
```

Since it is a `pointer` you can not use `.` to access the members you must use `->`.

Comment: ah. gotcha. thanks. I have a lot of trouble with pointer syntax!

Comment: @user2105982 In this case you might want to learn a bit about pointers, because if you have problems using them, it's incredibly easy to run into problems with them (ranging from leaks over crashes to strange behaviour). Also, since this answered your question, you should mark it as the correct answer by clicking the gray checkmark next to it!

Comment: Will do! I have to wait 6 minutes though.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `.` operator when the left-hand side is a direct object instance.

Use the `->` operator when the left-hand side is a pointer to an object instance.

The `->` operator is a combination of the `*` and `.` operators.  In other words, this code:

```
Dog->showHand();
```

Is the same as this code:

```
(*Dog).showHand();
```

Because the `*` operator first dereferences the pointer to gain access to the object instance, and then the `.` operator can access the object's members.